# Chrome (33) displaying inline-block different

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/3tBvG/

If you open the jsfiddle example, it gets displayed fine in older Chrome, Firefox, IE but in the newest Chrome version (33) it breaks the last `<a>` icon to new line:

Chrome 33:
[image]

Others [image]

Does someone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Interesting observation... if you open Chrome's developer tools and uncheck `display: inline-block` on that element, then re-check it, it looks correct.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, I've noticed that too in developer tools but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: The Facebook icon looks a little different. Maybe the width of one of those elements changes... I'm exploring right now.

Comment: @jmh010 All icons are embeded through Addthis plugin.

Comment: @user3187469 I meant that maybe it was rendered slightly different. An image or a border or a margin 1px off that was making the buttons wrap to a new line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved this: http://jsfiddle.net/3tBvG/4/

I just added `width: 100px;` into the buttons container div.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_20x20_style" style="display:inline-block; width: 100px;">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
</div>
```